# Swapping elements between 2 hashsets c#

Tags: c#, hashset

If I have 2 hashsets of size 5, how can I take x items from the first hashset and swap them with x items from the second one ?

For example :

```
          HashSet 1 has elements = {a , b, c , d ,e}
          HashSet 2 has elements = {r , s ,t ,u , w}
```

After the swap I would like to obtain:

```
          HashSet 1 = {r, s , c ,d e}
          HashSet 2 = {a, b, t , u ,w}
```

I don't need a speficic order.

Comment: By definition, the .NET `HashSet<T>` is a collection `whose elements are in no particular order.` Why are you talking about order?

Comment: I don't really care about a specific order, I just need to swap items between 2 hashsets

Comment: So you want to pick any X items from set 1, any X items from set 2, and swap them?

Comment: you should provide an example of what you want to do then, because it isn't making sense

Comment: Explain in detail what you really want to do. What are you trying to do that "swaping items between hashsets" is the solution? Also please include some example code of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: It is now reworded. How can we reopen the question? I would like to post another answer...

Comment: There must be enough reopen votes (only 1 missing).

Comment: How many reputation is needed to be able to vote for reopen?

Comment: @EvilFonti: at least 3000 rep: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question (the owner of the question must have 250 to vote to reopen his own)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
HashSet<string> hash1 = new HashSet<string>() { "A1", "B1", "C1", "D1" };
HashSet<string> hash2 = new HashSet<string>() { "A2", "B2", "C2", "D2" };
var firstThreeInOne = hash1.Take(3).ToList();
var firstThreeInTwo = hash2.Take(3).ToList();
foreach (string str in firstThreeInOne)
    hash1.Remove(str);
foreach (string str in firstThreeInTwo)
    hash2.Remove(str);
foreach (string str in firstThreeInTwo)
    hash1.Add(str);
foreach (string str in firstThreeInOne)
    hash2.Add(str);
```

Test:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", hash1)); // C2,B2,A2,D1
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", hash2)); // C1,B1,A1,D2
```

But note that a HashSet does not guarantee insertion order. It is simply not an ordered collection.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) mentions that explicitly:

> The `HashSet<T>` class provides high-performance set operations. A set
>   is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, **and whose
>   elements are in no particular order.**

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thank you Tim Schmelter! The order doesn't really bother me since the hashset will be evaluated as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

You can't unless you will implement hashset with ordering.
`HashSet` class of CLR has not ordering, and you can't get "first N" elements

Comment: Hm. It implements the IEnumerable interface which iterates through the set in an order, obviously. Although there may not be a formal guarantee I'd be amazed if that order changed for an unmodified set.

Comment: @Peter Schneider The original question I've answered was formulated like 'how to swap first five elements of two hashsets'. My answer is about impossibility to determine - what elements it could be.

Answer (score 0):

As DarkFalcon and others said the HashSet per definition has no order and therefor there are no first x elements in it.

BUT as with every collection you can get elements with the ElementAt method in some kind of order.

Be aware that you cannot know WHICH of the elements are counted as the first ones...

```
void Main()
{               
      var hashSet1 = new HashSet<int>();
      hashSet1.Add(1);
      hashSet1.Add(2);
      hashSet1.Add(3);
      hashSet1.Add(4);
      hashSet1.Add(5);

      var hashSet2 = new HashSet<int>();
      hashSet2.Add(6);
      hashSet2.Add(7);
      hashSet2.Add(8);
      hashSet2.Add(9);
      hashSet2.Add(0);

    SwapHashSets(hashSet1, hashSet2, 3);    
}


private List<int> GetXValuesFromHashSet(HashSet<int> hashSet, int count)
{
  var list = new List<int>();

  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
      list.Add(hashSet.ElementAt(i));
  }

  return list;
}

private void SwapHashSets(HashSet<int> hashSet1, HashSet<int> hashSet2, int count )
{
  var list1 = GetXValuesFromHashSet(hashSet1, count);
  var list2 = GetXValuesFromHashSet(hashSet2, count);

  foreach (var value in list1)
  {
      hashSet1.Remove(value);
  }

  foreach (var value in list2)
  {
      hashSet2.Remove(value);
  }

  foreach (var value in list1)
  {
      hashSet2.Add(value);
  }

  foreach (var value in list2)
  {
      hashSet1.Add(value);
  }

}
```

Comment: This approach has an issue if both sets have common items. You have to remove all first, otherwise Add can fail.

Comment: No it doesn't. If you add a present value to the HashSet the add method will just return a false instead of true and that's it. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb353005%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You need to remove all items first anyway, because otherwise you'll get a `false` which prevents the items from being added. Consider what happens with sets like `hashSet1 = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }` and `hashSet2 = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }`. The corect result would be that both sets remain unchanged. Your method removes all from the second set. I would also suggest to make the methods generic so that they can be used with any type instead of only `int`.